# How to keep a table row selected across multiple Views AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

On the left side of my Layout page there is a table with a list of Job Names. To the right is where the views populate. My views each have identical tables. ChangeOrders.cshtml, PurchaseOrders.cshtml, etc...  Right now when you are on the ChangeOrders view nothing appears until you select a job from the Job Names table. The ChangeOrders with that JobId appear. However when I switch to another view the job Selection clears itself. I need that Job to stay selected until I select another Job or a clear filter button is pressed.

Jobs Table on the Layout Page

```
<table class=" table table-bordred table-striped table-hover" ng-table=" tableparams" show-filter="true" ng-scroll-viewport style="height:200px;">
    <tr ng-repeat="job in jobArray" class="pointer" ng-click="selectJob(job)">
        <td data-title="'Job Name'" sortable="'JobName'" filter="{ 'JobName': 'text' }">{{job.JobName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ChangeOrder.cshtml (All other views will identical except the data)

```
<table class=" table table-bordred table-striped table-hover" ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" >
    <tr ng-repeat="job in selectedJob().ChangeOrders" class=" pointer">
        <td ng-click="editChangeOrderModal(job)" data-title="'CO Number'" sortable="'ChangeOrderNumber'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderNumber': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrderNumber}}</td>
        <td data-title="'CO Date'" sortable="'ChangeOrderDate'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderDate': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrderDate | date : date : shortDate}}</td>
        <td data-title="'CO Name'" sortable="'ChangeOrderName'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderName': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrderName}}</td>
        <td data-title="'CO Amount'" sortable="'ChangeOrderAmount'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderAmount': 'text' }">${{job.ChangeOrderAmount | number : fractionSize}}</td>
        <td data-title="'CO ApprovedDate'" sortable="'ChangeOrderApprovedDate'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderApprovedDate': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrderApprovedDate | date : date : shortDate}}</td>
        <td data-title="'CO ApprovedAmount'" sortable="'ChangeOrderApprovedAmount'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderApprovedAmount': 'text' }">${{job.ChangeOrderApprovedAmount | number : fractionSize}}</td>
        <td data-title="'CO ApprovedNumber'" sortable="'ChangeOrderApprovedNumber'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderApprovedNumber': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrderApprovedNumber}}</td>
        <td data-title="'CO Attn'" sortable="'ChangeOrderAttn'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderAttn': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrderAttn}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
//Sync Table Selections
$scope.selectJob = function (job) {
    $rootScope.selectedJob = job;
};
```

Updated 
I am using ngStorage for my sessionStorage
[ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)
I tried to implement it but I am not sure how to use it with the $rootScope. I also need to add the jquery function as well.

```
$scope.selectJob = function (job) {
    $rootScope.selectedJob = $sessionStorage.$default(job);
    console.log($rootScope.selectedJob);
};
$scope.selectedJob = $scope.selectedJob = function () {
    return $rootScope.selectedJob;
};
$('#myTable').on('click', ' tbody tr', function (event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: Are you running a single page application with `ngRoute` or `ui-router`?  If you are not the `$rootScope` will not persist across view changes.  If you absolutely can't run an SPA you could save the value to a `cookie` or `session` value.

Comment: its a MVC webapi Application, It should be SPA, correct? Isn't that why the views show up in the @RenderBody(). I only use the ngRoute for certain partial views inside the cshtml. What should I do?

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) it gives you a run down of how an AngularJS SPA is set up. Basically if you are not interested in running a full SPA you will have to save your values using the browser(session/cookie) then have the controller check for the value when it starts.

Comment: I wish I could start over at this point but I need to get this up and running ASAP. Can you give me some links on saving the session/cookie. Or do I need to submit a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary of the Problem

> As discussed `$rootScope` is being cleared because your current
>   application setup is not an `AngularJS` Single Page App.  It is
>   understandable that you can not switch it out at this time and that is
>   ok, your application will still be a nice switch to some angular.

In order to have data be persistent across views you will need to save the data in some form of client storage then check for the values when a controller loads and populate your values.

---

## Several Storage Options

**1) HTML5 Storage**

[Here is a an article about `HTML5` storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).  There are two types of `html5` web storage.

- **localStorage**

  - This can be very flexible it persists across sessions and tabs.  But if you want it to clear it *has* to be manually clearedk, so it can be considered insecure depending on what you are storing.
- **sessionStorage**

  - `sessionStorage` is almost identical to local storage *except* it does not save after the session ends.  So it is not available on a new window.

If you are interrested in this option these objects are not hard to work with on your own.  But if you found it easier you could use [this project](https://github.com/fredricrylander/angular-webstorage), which wraps the objects in an angular factory.

**2) Cookies**

While a valid storage option.   Cookies are really meant if you want to share the data serverside and want the data sent in the headers.

Angular has modules for handling cookies.  ***You have to download `angular-cookies` from the AngularJS site and include it to use ngCookies***. [Angular API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies)

Angular cookies can be implemented in two ways

- **`$cookie`** ([API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)) which is a basic wrapper for the `document.cookie` object.  And sets named values.
- **`$cookieStore`** ([API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)) has the same base functionality but uses a `(key,value)` format.

Comment: Excellent information. Thank you. I have updated my post for help with using the sessionStorage with my $rootScope and jquery. Thanks